# question about switching shader programs (ES 2)

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, shader

I'm trying to write a rather simple opengl es 2 program.

I have two different shaders, one renders a solid color rectangle to the screen, the other one renders a texture mapped rectangle.

I want to first draw the solid color rectangle, and then on top of it, draw the texture mapped rectangle.

```
    glUseProgram(program1);
  glUniform1f(shader1_uniforms[UNIFORM_SCREEN_WIDTH], (GLfloat)screenWidth);
  glUniform1f(shader1_uniforms[UNIFORM_SCREEN_HEIGHT], (GLfloat)screenHeight);

  glDisableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEX2);

  glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX2, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX2);
  glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_COLOR2, 4, GL_FLOAT, 1, 0, squareColors);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_COLOR2);


  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);


   glEnable(GL_BLEND);
   glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,1);




  glUseProgram(program2);
  glUniform1f(shader2_uniforms[UNIFORM_SCREEN_WIDTH], (GLfloat)screenWidth );
  glUniform1f(shader2_uniforms[UNIFORM_SCREEN_HEIGHT], (GLfloat)screenHeight);
  glUniform1i(shader2_uniforms[UNIFORM_UIMAP], 0);



  glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
  glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_COLOR, 4, GL_FLOAT, 1, 0, squareColors);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_COLOR);
  glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareTexCoords);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEX);

  // Draw
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);


   glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

the two shaders work correctly, if executed separately (for example, comment the part using the first shader). but when i combine them together, like the above, the texture map will disappear. I spent quite awhile trying to figure out why...

can someone help me? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine shaders that way, only the last program specified with glUseProgram will be used.

To combine shaders, you must do it manually generating a new shader which does both things at the same time.

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but I wonder if you might expand on this answer, please? Do you mean that you cannot use multiple shader programs, or are you saying that it needs doing in a particular way. I am trying to implement multiple shaders in my app at the moment - I started using just one, but a branch in the fragment shader caused a serious slow down. Thanks

Comment: @StuDev Means you can't use multiple programs at the same time, each call to glUseProgram will replace the current program with the one passed to the function. Note that this means at the same time, drawing objects each with different programs will work without any problems.

Comment: Ok thanks for replying. So if I understand correctly, the following pattern should work ok within a single frame render: `glUseProgram(prog1)` -> `glDrawElements()` -> `glUseProgram(prog2)` -> `glDrawArrays()` (to different FBO) -> present renderbuffer. Hope I've understood that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the glBindTexture() must happen after the program is switched with glUseProgram().  Here's a reference for glUseProgram [this page](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUseProgram.xml).  Make sure glUseProgram is not being called between glBegin and glEnd.  Check glGetError to see if an error is caused when loading the second vertex program.